# Are fields in Java private by default?

Tags: java

Why do i see so many examples out there that type private in front of a field while afaik fields are private by default.

```
private int number;
int number;
//Both of these are the same afaik. Yet, in a ton of examples private gets fully written, why?
```

Comment: Because explicit is better then implicit.

Comment: if you dont explicitly mention a variable as private, its scope will be default/package access. private is not same as default as private variables are accessible only inside the class

Comment: Is your question about Java or C# (I didn't work with C# yet but what you described in your question is not true in Java).

Comment: @Pshemo Java, but i guess it counts for any language where you do not have to declare a access modifier.

Comment: @MennoGouw No, the rules are not the same for any language. It's already different in Java than it is in C#, for example.

Comment: @MennoGouw clarify meaning of afaik plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski AFAIK == as far as I know

Comment: @KickButtowski Just look it up on Google; that's what I did when I first saw this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, they're not the same. The lack of an access modifier defaults to package-private.

See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public        Y        Y       Y         Y 
protected     Y        Y       Y         N
no modifier   Y        Y       N         N
private       Y        N       N         N
```

The exception to this rule is that `interface` method and field signatures are `public` when an access modifier is omitted: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

Comment: No modifier in Java is the same as protected.

Comment: What is the **Package**?

Comment: I have run eclipse right now to check it. Yes it is, you can access to the field which has no modifier in subclass. So there is error in your table.

Comment: `class A {
 int val;
}
class B extends A {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new B().val = 4;
 }
}`

Comment: @August You might amend your answer to mention that `interface` definitions are an exception to your table. In an `interface`, methods and static fields without an access modifier are implicitly `public`.

Comment: @Yoda move one of them to a _different package_ and try.

Comment: @Pshemo Haha, what for, I am talking about `no modifier` not `private`.

Comment: @Yoda it's not. package-private (default) is not accessible from a subclass if the subclass is an a different package. While protected it is.

Comment: @WilliamPrice Good idea, will do.

Comment: @Yoda OK, my mistake :), than move `B` to new package :)

Answer (score 5):

By default is not private, is "package only" (no key word for that).

All classes in same package see the field.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the same thing. Not specifying an access modifier in Java, in this case `private`, means that the default access modifier is used. i.e Anything on the same package with your class has access to those members.

The `private` access modifier means that only that specific class will have acess to it's members.

The reason this happens is for a class to protect it's data and avoid accidental data corruption. 
Please refer to [**this**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more info. 
 Now if you want to access those members you have to create getter methods for example:

```
public class foo{

   private int x = 5;

   public int getX(){ return x;}
}
```

Similarly if you want to change a members value you create setter methods:

```
 public int setX(int x){ this.x = x;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify any modifier to any property/method then, it has default modifier.
Which means it can be only accessed within same class or package. Whereas a private modifier restrict the property to be accessed within the defined class.

Answer (score 0):

The above link is valid and you should read it to see which access modifier can be applied to a class, struct, variable and etc....
But, in C# when no access modifier is available as in your second reference then the modifier is private by default, not internal. Internal is for classes and structs.

For Java is package visible

e.g.

class A{}

is the same with

internal class A{}